# Does Origin really delete games you haven't played for a while?

Tags: origin

It's a bit of a silly question, but I want to be sure.

My friend keeps insisting that Origin deletes games (both F2P games and paid ones) from your account if you don't play them for a while. Is that true?

Comment: Why would they do that?  Deleting paid for games is a lawsuit waiting to happen, and F2P games WANT you to have them installed on their hard drives.  It makes no sense for Origin to just up and delete them.

Comment: I thought the same, but someone I know kept telling me this and didn't look like he's kidding.

Comment: He's pulling your leg.  There's literally no reason whatsoever Origin would ever do that.

Comment: Again, I think like you, I just want to make sure. Thanks.

Comment: None of my games went missing during the time I didn't use Origin (a few months), not even the free ones.

Comment: @fbueckert Who knows, maybe bandwidth was more expensive when such rules were thought up. [Digital River still does this](https://store.digitalriver.com/DRHM/store?Action=DisplayDownloadInformationPage&SiteID=capcomus&Locale=en_US&ThemeID=1944700&Env=BASE#q9), which companies such as Capcom use. If you have to reinstall a game after two years, buy it again =/

Comment: @Louis I had issues with that when I bought a copy of MS Office through them. It's an incredibly outdated business model.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## NO, not anymore.

[Previously](http://www.rockpapershotgun.com/2011/08/03/origin-to-delete-inactive-accounts/), Section 5 of the EA read (emphasis mine):

> 5. Content and Entitlement Availability
>
> Entitlements may only be held in Accounts belonging to legal residents of countries where access to and use of Content and Entitlements is permitted. Entitlements may be purchased or acquired only from EA or an authorized retailer. EA reserves the right to refuse your request(s) to acquire Entitlements, and EA reserves the right to limit or block any request to acquire Entitlements for any reason.
>
> We do not guarantee that any Content or Entitlement will be available at all times or at any given time or that we will continue to offer particular Content or Entitlements for any particular length of time. We reserve the right to change and update Content and Entitlements without notice to you. **If you have not used your Entitlements or Account for twenty four (24) months or more and your Account has associated Entitlements, your Entitlements will expire and your Account may be cancelled for non-use.** Once you have redeemed your Entitlements, that content is not returnable, exchangeable, or refundable for other Entitlements or for cash, or other goods or services.

However, [the version last changed on September 4, 2012](http://tos.ea.com/legalapp/WEBTERMS/US/en/PC/#section5) reads:

> 5. EA Services, Content and Entitlement Availability
>
> Entitlements may only be held in Accounts belonging to legal residents of countries where access to and use of Content and Entitlements is permitted.  Entitlements may be purchased or acquired only from EA or an authorized retailer.  EA reserves the right to refuse your request(s) to acquire Entitlements, and EA reserves the right to limit or block any request to acquire Entitlements for any reason.
>
> We do not guarantee that any Content or Entitlement will be available at all times, in all countries and/or geographic locations, or at any given time or that we will continue to offer particular Content or Entitlements for any particular length of time. We reserve the right to change and update Content and Entitlements without notice to you.  Once you have redeemed your Entitlements, that content is not returnable, exchangeable, or refundable for other Entitlements or for cash, or other goods or services.

In addition, EA claimed that this provision was [designed to guard against creation of non-active accounts for inappropriate reasons](http://www.rockpapershotgun.com/2011/08/04/eas-comment-on-origin-account-deletion/).

Answer (score -3):

Well, you're wrong.

Just because they took it out of their service agreement doesn't meant that they still don't do it.

I had purchased the latest installment of SimCity on the day it was released and I got the deluxe edition, it was like $75. Anyway, I played for two weeks, had a great time doing so. Then there was an update. After the update, I could no longer play the game. It just went to a black screen and did nothing. I scoured the internet for tips on how to fix the issue, but to no avail. This was well after your post stating they no longer practice this treachery. Well, every once in awhile, I check back to see if the next update will be the one where my problem has been fixed and I can resume playing the game I paid for. Today, I went to origin, logged in, nothing in the account. No SimCity, No Battlefield 3, which I got for free because Origins servers were too crappy to handle the traffic of the amount of games they sold.

THEY CAN STILL JACK YOUR STUFF AS OF 6/2/2014

Comment: Do you have any proof of this?

Comment: This happened to a lot of people and maybe if you read the emails origin sent, they apologised for the issue and gave everyone a free game, then you reinstalled sim city. Don't rely on waiting for a patch that might never come. as for the games missing just log compaint with their helpdesk, ORIGIN has a fantastic help desk especially compared to steam